# How to check if one value from one column is present in another cell of another column?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to process data from a DataFrame containing various columns like "Start", "End", "Identifier", and "SW Value". This is what one row looks like in Excel.

Since the SW value contains the Identifier;Start, I want to say it's a match. I don't know how to implement this. I also want to see if the start value matches, but it's a decimal

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frWMN.png)

I tried to convert both identifier and SW value to lowercase before the check to make sure it wasn't a problem because of case sensitivity, but it still says no match instead of yes.

This is what I did:

```
def is_identifier_contained(identifier, sw_value):
    if identifier.lower() in sw_value.lower():
        return True
    else:
        return False

                # Check if identifier is contained in sw value
                if start_numerical_count == 1 and end_numerical_count == 0 and identifier_count == 1:
                    identifier = str(row["Identifier"])
                    sw_value = str(row["SW Value"])

                    if is_identifier_contained(identifier, sw_value):
                        table.at[i, "Identifier in SW Value"] = "Yes"
                    else:
                        table.at[i, "Identifier in SW Value"] = "No"
                else:
                    table.at[i, "Identifier in SW Value"] = "N/A"
```

Comment: Show us your actual code.  Otherwise we have no idea what you tried or what you did wrong.